# Batch file to run an application placed on share drive

Tags: batch-file

I am not able to run my batch file which is located on Share Drive..However it runs perfectly when the location is Desktop or local drive

Batch File Code:

```
cd "\\\172.17.23.42\Extra\"
"SL - EOD.acsauto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must download the `PsExec.exe` tools from this link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Then, you type this command:

```
PsExec.exe -h -s \\NameOrIpOfYourServer -c -v PathFile_In_your_pc\file.bat
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thank u so much for your quick response...but can you please tell me how to use PsExec.exe and above code shared by you.

Comment: Its simple, you must download the tools from the link, then you copy this `PsExec.exe` to you desktop for exemple, after that, you run the cmd line from Desktop (Shift+Right-Click and Open Command Window here) and you type the code.

PsExec.exe -h -s \\NameOrIpOfYourServer -c -v PathBatchFile\file.bat

Comment: Superb...but my problem is I want to enable this with VBA, and everyone will access through this VBA code from share drive.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please, you mean that you want to call your batch file from VBA ? –